# Encrypted environment variables in .net core app

Tags: .net-core, environment-variables, .net-5

In my .net core app (.net5), I'd like to store my environment variables values encrypted. This means I need to decrypt the values when loaded via EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider. For example,
`SET Product_SecretKeyEnc=#$SELOW#RLJLSKDFJ`

In the product I'd like this realized as a configuration value "SecretKey" with a value of "DecryptedString"

So, I'd like to translate the key and the value during bootstrap.

This application is hosted in AWS Elastic Beanstalk which does not have integration with AWS Secrets Manager. [AWS EB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html) recommends storing configuration in environment variables. But I understand these are not secured. My intent in encrypting the environment variables is to prevent someone from getting a dump from being able to get anything useful.

Note: Andrew Lock does have a great [blog post](https://andrewlock.net/secure-secrets-storage-for-asp-net-core-with-aws-secrets-manager-part-2/) on using AWS Secrets Manager from .net core. But I thought the encrypted environment variables would suffice.

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt environment variables?

Comment: Sensitive data requiring encryption is almost undoubtedly not appropriate to store in environment variables. Can you elaborate a bit on your use case to ensure this isn't some form of XY problem?

Comment: @TomW I've added clarification to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenter that you may be XY'ing this a bit, and that storing encrypted environment variables is not a good idea.

That said, if you persist, then what you need to do is implement your own provider derived from `EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider` that knows how to identify which environment variables are encrypted and knows how to decrypt them.

You'd then add it to the set of configuration providers in the usual way.

Comment: I did look at that. But, the Load() is internal. So, I think I'd probably have to copy the provider source and monkey with that. 

Right now, I created an extension method that mutates the values directly in Environment before registering the configuration provider. #yuck.

In the end, will probably go the AWS Secrets Manager route.